# How far from PC should i Put my HDMI splitter?

Tags: hdmi, desktop-computer

I have a PC and want to connect with two monitors and 1 projector. 1 monitor is near the PC, the projector is 15 m far from pc, and the other monitor is 30 m far from pc. 
i have 2 HDMI cables 15 m each and a HDMI splitter. 
I can get signal from projector but not form the monitor that is 30 m away. How can i fix this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia's article on HDMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Cables), the problem is the length of your cables. Good quality cables can reach lengths of up to 15 meters, but lower quality cables will have problems beyond 5 meters. You are trying to go 30 meters, and that's just too far.

What you want is to use an HDMI extender, which is a powered device. Apparently, HDMI extenders consisting solely of active HDMI cables can handle up to 30 meters which is right on the very edge of what you are trying. Better, you want one based on HDBaseT or similar, good for 100 meters or further.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your response. 
Actually I am using powered HDMI splitter that in the same time can extend the transmission distance and improves transmission signal. I am trying to put the splitter 15 m away from the source and 15 m away from the monitor. 

p.s. With just 15 m the signal is perfect.